# Can one compose types in a Haskell instance declaration?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've written a Haskell typeclass and it would be convenient to declare instances of it using types of the form `(a -> m _)`, where `m` is of kind `(* -> *)`, such as a monad, and `_` is a slot to be left unsaturated. I know how to write `newtype X a m b = X (a -> m b)`, and declaring an instance for `X a m`. But what I'm looking for is to instead use the bare, unwrapped `->` type, if that's possible.

If one wants to declare instances for types of the form `(a -> _)`, then you can just write:

```
instance Foo a ((->) a) where ...
```

but I don't know how/whether one can do it with types of the form `(a -> m _)`. I guess I'm looking to compose the type constructor `(->) a _` and the type constructor `m _` in my instance declaration.

I'd like to write something like this:

```
instance Foo a ((->) a (m :: *->*)) where ...
```

or:

```
instance Foo a ((->) a (m *)) where ...
```

but of course these don't work. Is it possible to do this?

Concretely, here's what I'm trying to achieve. I wrote a typeclass for
MonadReaders that are embedded inside (one level) of other MonadReaders,
like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies FlexibleInstances
UndecidableInstances  #-}

class MonadReader w m => DeepMonadReader w r m | m -> r where
  { deepask   :: m r
  ; deepask = deepreader id
  ; deeplocal :: (r -> r) -> m a -> m a
  ; deepreader :: (r -> a) -> m a
  ; deepreader f = do { r <- deepask; return (f r) }
  }

instance MonadReader r m => DeepMonadReader w r (ReaderT w m) where
  { deepask = lift ask
  ; deeplocal = mapReaderT . local
  ; deepreader = lift . reader
  }
```

It'd be nice to also provide an instance something like this:

```
instance MonadReader r m => DeepMonadReader w r ((->) w (m :: * ->
*)) where
  { deepask = \w -> ask
  ; deeplocal f xx = \w -> local f (xx w)
  ; deepreader xx = \w -> reader xx
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the wrong track and are making things a lot more
complicated than they need to be.

Some observations:

> ... ((->) w (m :: * -> *)) ...

Let's explore what you mean by this. You are using it for the type parameter `m` in your `DeepMonadReader` class, and therefore it needs to be a monad. Can you give a concrete example of a monad which
has this type? Why not just use `((->) w)` ?

> class MonadReader w m => DeepMonadReader w r m | m -> r where ...

The fact that `w` never apears in any member signatures is an indication something is amiss.

> ... I wrote a typeclass for MonadReaders that are embedded inside (one level) of other MonadReaders ...

I would take the reverse perspective. It makes sense to talk of monad stacks which are a transformed
version of another monad stack. E.g.:

```
StateT s (WriterT w IO)   "contains"     IO
WriterT w (Maybe a)       "contains"     Maybe a
```

And what does it mean for a monad stack **m1** to "contain" another monad **m2**?
It just means that there is a way to convert computations in **m2** to computations in **m1**:

```
convert ::  m2 a -> m1 a
```

Of course, this is just `lift` when using monad transformers.

To express your concept of a monad reader embedded in another monad, I would use this
type class:

```
class HasReader m m' r where ...
  deepAsk :: m r
  deepLocal :: (r -> r) -> m' a -> m a
```

The idea here is that an instance **HasReader m m' r** expresses the fact that
monad **m** "contains" a monad **m'** which itself is a reader with
environment **r**.

**deepAsk** returns the environment of **m'** but as a computation in **m**.

**deepLocal** runs a computation in **m'** with a environment modification function
but returns it as a computation in **m**.  Note how this type signature is different from yours:
my **deepLocal** uses different monads, **m'** and **m** whereas yours just goes from **m** to **m**.

The next step is decide which triples **(m, m', r)** do we want to write instances
of **HasReader** for. Clearly it seems you had instances like this in mind:

```
m                                    m'                           r
---------------------                -----------                  --
ReaderT s (ReaderT r m)              ReaderT r m                  r
ReaderT t (ReaderT s (ReaderT r m)   ReaderT s (Reader T r m)     s
...
```

but it also seems reasonable to want to have these instances:

```
StateT s (ReaderT r m)               ReaderT r m                  r
WriterT w (ReaderT r m)              ReaderT r m                  r
MaybeT (ReaderT r m)                 ReaderT r m                  r
...
```

It turns out, though, that we don't need the **HasReader** class for any of these cases.
We can just write the expression as a computation in **m'** and `lift` it up to **m**.

Comment: Thank you for this. You are making several suggestions: (1) That I change the type of the instance to (->) w, or change the first parameter of the class from the type of the outer Reader environment to the type of the outer Reader monad. (2) That I change the type of deepLocal. (3) That I might want to have instances of the class for monad stacks that only have a single layer of Readers; and that in many such cases the class isn't that useful or necessary.

Comment: Responding to (1): this is worth exploring, thanks. Re (2): I need a deepLocal with the type I described; though it could be there are advantages I'm not yet seeing to building it in terms of the deepLocal you propose. I'll think about this.

Comment: Re (3): indeed we don't need the HasReader class for your second group of cases, and we don't need to do the `lift`ing ourselves, either, because it's already written into the MonadReader instances for your `m` monads. My `DeepMonadReader` class is for the cases where an outer MonadReader in the stack "gets in the way" of a more deeply embedded MonadReader, making the latter's `ask` and `local` methods harder to access. Of course one can always still get at them using the right combinations of `lift`, `mapReader` and so on; but these combinations aren't always obvious...

Comment: Re (3) - why don't you give a concrete example of a case where you want to use the DeepReader class, and we'll see what the options are.

Comment: Continuing this discussion on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115069/room-re-stackoverflow-q-37906891)...